# Is there a symbol that denotes a finite set?

Tags: logic, notation

Let's say I want to say there exists a finite set $S$.

If I write $\exists S$ it is not obvious from the notation that $S$ is finite.

How can I show that $S$ is finite in notation form?

Comment: You could write $|S|<\aleph_0$ or $|S|< \infty$ but lots of people just write, "Let $S$ be a finite set ...$

Comment: When working with finite sets, in practice it often suffices to consider the numbers $1$ through $n$, which are typically denoted as $[n]$.

Comment: $S=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$

Comment: The best notation is "$S$ is a finite set".

Comment: Are you trying to write a formal logical statement or a natural language statement? If the former, then you can write $\exists S(|S| < \omega \Rightarrow \ldots )$. If the latter, then (IMHO) you shouldn't be writing $\exists S$ - most attempts to use logical symbolism inside natural language narrative lead to misunderstanding and misery in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

*How can I show that S is finite in notation form?*

The answer depends strongly on the context.

In contexts where the elements of $S$ are important, the notation $S=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ is convenient. Consider, for example, the following sentences where $X$ and $Y$ are given vector spaces:

> (1) There exists $S\subset X$ such that $\operatorname{span}(S)=Y$.
>
> (2) There exists $S=\{x_1,...,x_n\}\subset X$ such that $\operatorname{span}(S)=Y$.

Sentence (1) says that $Y$ is a vector subspace of $X$.

Sentence (2) says that $Y$ is a finite-dimensional vector subspace of $X$. Also, it introduces an upper bound for the dimension of $Y$ (which is $n$) and a particular form for any element $y$ of $Y$, namely,
$$y=\alpha_1x_1+\cdots +\alpha_nx_n.$$

So, in the context of linear algebra, the notation $S=\{x_1,\ldots ,x_n\}$ says that $S$ is finite in very useful way.

To get more accurate answers, give more details on your context.